# JavaScript is returning the error: Uncaught TypeError: someLink.select is not a function

Tags: javascript

JavaScript is returning the error: Uncaught TypeError: clickerLink.select is not a function.

I'm trying to make a button copy a certain string. 
`<button class="something" onclick="myFunction()">copy</button>`\

```
function myFunction(){
    let someLink = "loadstring(game:HttpGet('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnWickey/roblox-exploits/main/clickerMadness/main.lua'))()";
    someLink.select();
    someLink.setSelectionRange(0, 999999); // For mobile devices, if somehow there's an executor for Android or maybe even iOS.
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(someLink.value)
}
```

Does anyone have an answer? Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm new to programming.

Comment: what is select()?

Comment: What do you think `someLink` is? It appears to be a string which has neither `select()` nor `setSelectionRange()` functions - at least according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). These may be extensions provided by some other library or framework though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you see your console , it says that :

```
Uncaught TypeError: someLink.select is not a function
```

so I changed your function a little and it works :

```
        function myFunction(){
            let someLink = "loadstring(game:HttpGet('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnWickey/roblox-exploits/main/clickerMadness/main.lua'))()";
            // someLink.select();
            // someLink.setSelectionRange(0, 999999); // For mobile devices, if somehow there's an executor for Android or maybe even iOS.
            someLink = someLink.substring(0, 999999);
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(someLink)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!
I found out that you can just `navigator.clipboard.writeText('loadstring(game:HttpGet("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JohnWickey/roblox-exploits/main/clickerMadness/main.lua"))())');` and it will work, but still, thanks for going through my code and fixing it.

Answer (score -1):

This has worked for me previously, give it a go :)

```
        function copy(el) {
            var body = document.body,
            range, sel;
            if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
                range = document.createRange();
                sel = window.getSelection();
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                range.selectNodeContents(el);
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
            document.execCommand("Copy");
        }
```